# UINavigationBar background image does not change with rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uiappearance

I am trying to use a background image using the appearance methods in iOS 5.  I’m setting the background images with these statements:

```
UIImage *portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_portrait.png"];
UIImage *landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_landscape.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:portraitImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:landscapeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

When I run the app, the correct image appears in portrait and landscape, but when I rotate back to portrait, it still has the landscape image shown.

I created a sample test application here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7834263/Appearance%20Test.zip

And screen shots of what is happening:

[image: normal portrait]

[image: normal landscape]

[image: incorrect portrait]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried changing your code to the following & it worked just fine for me.

```
UIImage *portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_portrait.png"];
UIImage *landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_landscape.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:portraitImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:landscapeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks , this does the trick. But since I am using AutoLayout in my application , is it safe to use autoresizingMask ? As per my knowledge when we use AutoLayout , we don't use autoresizingMask. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Autolayout can be used alongside autoresizingMasks. You're autoresizingMasks will be translated into auto layout. See UIView property: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
let portraitImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Navbar.portrait.png")!
let landscapeImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Navbar.landscape.png")!
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(portraitImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(landscapeImage, forBarMetrics: .CompactPrompt)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleTopMargin
```

Comment: For me, only `.Compact` bar metric works for landscape mode